# how to hide id = from url using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I need the url
from

```
localhost/project/category?c=electronics
```

to

```
localhost/project/category/electronics
```

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)?$ /category.php?c=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^category/+?$ /category.php?c=$1  [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following htaccess rules. Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
##External redirect to url change in browser.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(project/category)\.php\?c=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to category.php in backend.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php?c=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^project/category/([0-9a-z]+)$ /project/category?c=$1 [L]
```

Why is "project/" missing in your original try ?

You have to specify the full path.
You can try this simple rewriteRule wich should works.